# How to set default value for user profile property (string property)?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, script, default-value, userprofiles

How to create SharePoint user profile property using powershell script with default value.Anyone suggest idea to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User Profile Properties doesn't support a Default Value

Answer (score 1):

you can create a workflow to set the value, but it will show up after the entry was created